# Mongoose refpath with external reference and internal

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

My database contains two different collections I have "groups" and I have "users". Each group has a field "participants" which is an array that contains either users or guests. Guests unlike users are stored in the group (since they're bound to the specific group).

I use the "participant" schema as an abstraction object between users/guests and the group, this way I can give different users different privileges.

Now to my problem. What I want is the "participant" schema to work for both users and guests which it would if guests would have been its own collection. However, in this case guests belong to the group object and I'm therefore not sure how I'm supposed to reference it. I've tried *enum: ["user", "guests"]* and *enum: ["user", "meetings.guests"]* but without any result. I only get the following error:
`MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "guests".`. This tells me that I obviously haven't understood how to reference/link subdocuments in the same collection.
**Note that I don't want guests to be their own collection**

Maybe I can somehow move the "guest" object to "participants.user" but then I would somehow have to tell mongo that it's not an ObjectId anymore but an object?

**Group.model.ts**

```js
export const ParticipantSchema = new Schema({
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        refPath: "participants.userModel"
    },
    userModel: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        enum: ["user", "guests"] // How am I supposed to connect the guests as reference? The guests don't have their own collection, they are stored inside the group
    },
    privilege: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    }
})

export const GroupSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String
    },
    participants: [ParticipantSchema],

    guests: [GuestSchema]
}, {
    timestamps: true
})
export default database.model("group", GroupSchema)
```

**User.model.ts**

```js
export const UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
})

export default database.model("user", UserSchema)
```

Comment: Did you find an answer for this?

Comment: Simple answer is no, I did not find a direct solution to this problem. What I did instead was that I went with a relational approach and created a new collection for guests, thus making it possible for me to reference them. It feels a bit weird since document based databases want as few joins/connections as possible but I couldn't find another solution. It's still a very structured way of doing it, the only concern I have is that the performance will take a hit.